# Возможно ли создать объектные типы данных внутри пакета?

Tags: sql, oracle, объекты, plsql

Возможно ли создать объектные типы данных внутри пакета?

Нечто подобное:

```
create or replace package my_package as 
    type my_type as object (
        id number(15) 
     ); 
end;
```

Завершится ошибкой:

> Error(3,9): PLS-00540: object not supported in this context.

В конечном итоге, хотел бы использовать полиморфизм, а также дать объектам доступ к таблицам и использовать PL/SQL, что недопустимо в типах, определенных вне пакетов.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [Possible to create Oracle Database object types inside of PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069176)
 от участника [@jlpp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30642/jlpp)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/1069176

Answer (score 2):

Основной упор при дизайне объектно ориентированных расширений БД был направлен на реализацию ORD ([Object-oriented Database Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_model#Object-oriented_database_models)). Поэтому, пользовательские (или объектные) типы данных могут быть созданы только в SQL, но испольоваться они могут без всяких ограничений в PL/SQL контексте.

Например, определим два новых типа данных (UDT=*user defined type*) унаследованых (*inheritance*) от одного абстрактного (ADT=*abstract data type*):

```
create or replace type tbase force as object (
    msg varchar2 (16),
    member function print return varchar2) not instantiable not final
/
create or replace type tdate under tbase (
    overriding member function print return varchar2) instantiable final
/
create or replace type ttime under tbase (
    overriding member function print return varchar2) instantiable final
/
```

Вся логика этих типов данных реализуется в их теле (*type body*). Использовать можно всё, что доступно в пакетах или блоках PL/SQL, например, статический и динамический SQL, внутренние PL/SQL типы данных, исключения и т.п.:

```
create or replace type body tdate as
    overriding member function print return varchar2 is
    begin 
        return self.msg||' '||to_char (sysdate, 'dd Mon'); end;
end;        
/
create or replace type body ttime as
    overriding member function print return varchar2 is
    begin 
        return self.msg||' '||to_char (sysdate, 'hh24:mi'); end;
end;        
/
```

Не только небольшой функционал, но и полностью всё приложение может быть реализовано как пользовательский тип данных:

```
create or replace type tappl force as object (
    name  varchar2 (16),
    member function main return char) instantiable final
/
create or replace type body tappl is
    member function main return char is
        function print (what tbase) return varchar2 is 
        begin return what.print; 
        end;
    begin  
        dbms_output.put_line (
            self.name||': '||print (tdate ('Сегодня'))||', '||print (ttime ('сейчас')));
        return 'ok';    
    end;
end;
/
```

Выше простейший пример полиморфизма (*polymorphism*) -- для каждго из экземпляров по ссылке на базовый тип данных будет вызвана своя функция `print`.

Для запуска этого небольшого прилижения потребуется всего лишь анонимный блок:

```
var ret char 
exec :ret := tappl ('Новости').main

Новости: Сегодня 15 Jul, сейчас 16:45

RET
--
ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Цитата из главы [3.1 Declaring and Initializing Objects in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/index.html) книги официальной документации [Object-Relational Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/declaring-initializing-objects-in-plsql.html#GUID-AA6DEB60-3D57-44CE-B0F6-D1AEC0B47AE0):

> Using object types in a PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package is a two-step process.
>
> 1. You **must define** object types **using the SQL** statement CREATE TYPE, in SQL*Plus or other similar programs.
>
>    After an object type is defined and installed in the schema, you can use it in any PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package.
> 2. In PL/SQL, you then declare a variable whose data type is the user-defined type or ADT that you just defined.

Так что, к сожалению, нет, создать объектные типы данных внутри пакета невозможно.

---

<sub>Свободные переводы [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069210) от участника [@l0b0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96588/l0b0), обьединённого с [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054302) от участника [@user272735](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272735/user272735)</sub>